# zip warning: name not matched compressing folders

Tags: zip, compression, archive

I'm trying to backup the whole volume of a drive.
I want to have it password-protected

This is what I did

```
zip -er archive.zip /Volumes/Storage/
```

But I'm getting zip warning: name not matched

Thanks!

Comment: `zip` is a tool to package and compress (archive) files. My suggestion is to first create a tarball (with `tar`) with the whole volume of the drive and afterwards compress it.

Comment: See [How would I use tar for full backup and restore with system on SSD and home on HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524418/how-would-i-use-tar-for-full-backup-and-restore-with-system-on-ssd-and-home-on-h)

Comment: ok I just tried with tar, it seemed to work, but it takes forever. any other way to accomplish this? thanks!

Comment: Have you compressed data? What flags did you use in your tar command?

Comment: See [Fastest way combine many files into one (tar czf is too slow)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/fastest-way-combine-many-files-into-one-tar-czf-is-too-slow)

Comment: I did tar -cvpzf

Comment: If its taking too long drop the `-z` flag. Compress and encrypt data when the tarball is complete.

Comment: was trying to back it up to S3, but they have limit on the single file size. How are you doing your backups?

Comment: If there is a size limit you may split the tarball into smaller files using the `split` utility.

Comment: See https://www.tecmint.com/split-large-tar-into-multiple-files-of-certain-size/amp/